# Asus Eee replacement netbook monitor doesn't fit connector

Tags: display, lcd, eee-pc, connector

I bought a replacement screen for an Asus Eee netbook 1005HA from a company that said the screen they were selling was compatible, but the connector on the replacement is smaller than the original.

I've scoured the net for instructions, but so far, I'm out of luck. As far as I can tell, they both have 32 pins, but maybe I'm missing a connector? The replacement is a LG Philips 10.1 inchs Glossy LED Panel Screen.

Here's a picture of the two connectors. The replacement is on the left:

[image]

Comment: your part link got lost; post it in a comment and a high-rep user can edit it in for you.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I may be in a similar situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact the company and explain the problem. Show them the difference between the connectors if necessary.

It was sold as compatible so you have a right to a replacement that is or a refund.

Comment: I've sent them an e-mail, but any idea if these are, indeed, incompatible connections? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Michael - sorry I can't help any further. If the connector doesn't fit with the cables you have then you either need a new screen or perhaps just the right connector.

Comment: @michael: sometimes DIY repairs do turn into "build-a-custom-connector" jobs.  but i'd take chrisF's advice here for now -- assume you didn't get the right part, and work with the company to try to get the right part.  unless someone else posts a specific adapter you need to buy/build, that's probably the fastest resolution you'll get.

Comment: @quack Thanks, I'll keep my fingers crossed for a reply.